Principal value of Cauchy type integral.
Can someone provide me with a sufficiently rigorous and complete proof of the following?
Let $\Omega$ be a simply connected domain whose boundary $\Omega$ is a smooth path, let $z\in\Omega$, then:
$$p.v.\int_{\partial\Omega} \frac{1}{w-z}\mathrm d w=i\pi,$$
where $p.v.$ denotes the Cauchy principal value of the integral. I already tried looking through several textbooks and found proofs for the general Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem, but I want a proof which focuses on this particular part and handles all the details.
I already saw the proof where they break up the contour/path and join it with the arc of a circle of radius going to zero in the limit, but I fail to see why the integral is exactly $i\pi$ as opposed to, say, $i\frac{\pi}{4}$. The argument is usually that as the circle gets smaller the arc gets closer to a semi-circle, and I can convince myself of this fact, but how does one prove it.
Thank you.

Look up Cauchy's integral formula for analytic functions.

@Medo thank you for the suggestion, I’ve edited the question and added more details.
